# Android app backend design

Tags: android, api, http, static-files

I have experience handling with database and web services such an API.

Now, my idea is to have some images stored on the server and in-app the user can list/view all of them and then choose one to customize.

After some research on the subject I found that one of the best approach is to have the files itself served as static content using an HTTP server and an API to serve all the remaining information including the static URL to the image.

I'm thinking of using Node.js for the backend and a database such mongoDB.

As this solution may seem good in a web-only environment and I'm not sure if it is on a mobile one.

So my question is: is this a good approach for a mobile + backend solution or there is something else I could try related to the protocol + architecture design for the communications between the client and server.

Comment: Please make sure to add some code so we can get a better picture of what's going on

Comment: @SígvardrÓlavrsson I haven't started to code yet. Looking for a good solution first.

Answer (score 0):

For my app I'm using **Node.js** for the backend as well since it's

- fast
- ideal for data-heavy websites and apps
- useful to build APIs

You are on the right way, but if you just want to serve images or data you can also check **Firebase** which is provided by **Google**. There are much more you can do with it.

Check this https://firebase.google.com/

It's free. So you don't need to pay for a **virtual server**, but it's limited.

See also this https://firebase.google.com/pricing/

Comment: Thank you for the tip!

I'm trying to stick with my own platform (the one I want to develop) because for now I just need to serve images but my goal is to keep adding features such Authentication, user profile, etc...

I'm not looking for "the easiest path"... I'm trying to learn new stuff and link that with my knowledge.

If you allow me to, can I ask you if you are using HTTP for "downloading" the static files and "proxying" the access through the API (by serving the static URL)? 

Thank you.

Comment: For loading data I'm using OkHttp and Picasso for images. They are both a framework of Square. Also, you also can use Authentication with Firebase.

Comment: Can you give me some details about the "upload" process? Is it a "plain, simple" HTTP POST? Thank you. (some links about the subject would be nice, if you have some)

Comment: Upload file to server? Using firebase or your own server?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Yes upload the file. In my case to my own server... My main struggle is to understand how the file upload is done (I mean in a efficient way).

Comment: There are many tutorials on web to do this. One of them is this http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/